# "--silent-debugger-extension-api" flag not working as expected

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium, microsoft-edge-extension, web-extension

I am getting this banner while using the chrome.debugger APIs. Earlier it was hidden if "--silent-debugger-extension-api" flag was used but from Chrome version 100 and above the flag is not working as expected.

Is there any other workaround to hide the banner?
Please see the attached image for more details.

Tried using "--silent-debugger-extension-api" flag
Also tried dispatchEvent apis to simulate the keystrokes but it didn't work as expected

Comment: It still works as usual. Make sure you've exited Chrome using the `Exit` command in its menu and use your OS task manager to verify there are no chrome processes left running.

Comment: @wOxxOm - Thanks for the suggestion.
We were trying to open the chrome window through the command line while the main window is already open. In this scenario, this flag is not working because chrome is already open. Is there any solution for the same? We are trying to do it for running automation.

Comment: No, the only solution is to completely exit the browser. It always worked like this.

Answer (score 0):

Same here as @wOxxOm has said. You have to close all the instances to get the flag to work. As a workaround, I suppose you can use other release channels like Beta, Dev and Canary, then you won't have to close the main window of the Stable channel.